# How to get current time in micro seconds?

Tags: ios, react-native

On iOS there is `CACurrentMediaTime` function that provides timestamp with nanosecond precision. 
This function is being used by `global.nativePerformanceNow` react-native function.

What I don't understand is what the returned value of this function represents, or since when the timestamp is calculated.

Answer (score 0):

global.nativePerformanceNow() seems to call the native functions CACurrentMediaTime() on iOS, and clock_gettime() on Android.

It seems like global.nativePerformanceNow() returns a floating point number representing the amount of milliseconds since device boot on both platforms but it isn't documented as far as I can find.